# What is the appropriate forum to ask where to find information about quantum computing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Since my question isn't really a software bug or problem to be solved, I'm not sure that StackOverflow is the right forum to ask it. Which forum is appropriate?

My question:

> I am wanting to learn more about computing using qubits. Specifically,
>   I want to attempt to simulate the behavior of qubits using classical
>   bits (obviously on a very small scale, and without the performance
>   benefits of doing the computation on an actual quantum computing
>   machine).
>
> Where can I find good tutorials, lessons, resources, or at least
>   correct information on the subject?
>
> If there are not very good resources on the subject of simulating
>   qubit computation using classical bits, resources that sufficiently
>   explain how to perform computation using qubits in the first place
>   would be sufficient.

Comment: That question looks very broad. I don't know if it can find a home on Stack Exchange in its current state. As an aside, if qubits could be simulated by "classical" bits, we would already be doing it.

Comment: *"Where can I find good tutorials, lessons, resources, or at least correct information on the subject?"* is **definitely** not on-topic anywhere on SE. Maybe consider http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/, but read their Help Center content **very carefully** before posting anything.

Comment: @Frederic, It would surprise me if the behavior of qubits cannot be at least closely approximated using classical bits. The following quote suggests such a simulation can be made:

["Given sufficient computational resources, however, a classical computer could be made to simulate any quantum algorithm, as quantum computation does not violate the Church–Turing thesis."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing)

Note: I am fine with extremely slow performance. I am not trying to achieve the performance advantages quantum computing offers in some cases - only simulating the behavior.

Comment: @Porthos, I wonder how you would implement [entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) accurately, though. As for [cstheory.se], their help page says they *welcome research-level questions* and defines *research-level* as *roughly when they can be discussed between two professors or between two graduate students working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and a typical undergraduate student.* They do have a [`[quantum-computing]`](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) tag, but you would have to improve your question a lot.

Comment: Nowhere.  This is why we have search engines.

Comment: Maybe it could be on-topic *and* off-topic at the same time, until you ask.

Comment: @Will, I wouldn't have taken the question here unless I had tried all searches I could think of first. Perhaps I am missing appropriate key words due to my in-expertise with the subject matter, or maybe there simply hasn't been much work done in this area, but I haven't found what I was looking for. There are times it is appropriate to ask a community or an expert for recommended resources instead of relying on the results that appear with my uneducated guess at search criteria.

Comment: Just because you tried and failed doesn't make the question on topic. There are no times at which asking for links is appropriate on the SE network.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).