# Is a question about why a question is downvoted legitimate in meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, downvote-reason

Can one *ever* legitimately ask why a question is downvoted/put on hold/closed here?

I've tried to ignore the occasional downvotes and question closures I get (not very many, thankfully), but it's been getting more frustrating of late. I don't think my communication and research skills are poor. Answers to a question about a downvoted question could tell me what I'm missing. Or, better yet, if people disagree with the downvotes, maybe that would shame the downvoters into being more thoughtful. (If better behavior is to be encouraged in askers and answerers, why not voters?)

At least one attempt to generate a broader discussion about the culture here has been closed down as "opinion-based," so I won't try to restart it. The question is simply: Can ask why a specific question is downvoted here?

PS I think *this* question is okay, despite being meta-meta, but what do I know?

Comment: You can, but I'm afraid that you have to make sure to phrase it well otherwise some users might think you're complaining. I've seen legitimate questions about closed/downvoted posts get very good responses, and very bad responses. It might depend upon how full the moon is or something. ;)

Comment: I would not focus the question on down votes, but rather on, "My question is being poorly received. What can I do to make my question better fit the site?" If you focus on the votes, you risk coming across as just complaining. Your goal is to figure out how, if at all, you can improve your post anyway. So focus on that.

Comment: +1 to what Kendra said. Being a meta lurker i can tell you there are a LOT of these questions around. The ones that get a good reception are usually the ones that a) are opened to the fact that their question aren't perfect (ie: what can i do to make this a better question vs i am getting illegitimate downvotes) and b) don't make it sound like a rant.... Like... AT ALL.  It's unfortunate but we see enough of these that even a whiff of a rant on your part usually means the reception of your meta question will be bad (not saying that's how it SHOULD be.... but what i've seen)

Comment: Side note you don't seem to have any questions on META - please clarify if you are asking about posts on META or SO.

Comment: "I think this question is okay, despite being meta-meta" It's OK to talk about ***M***SO on MSO itself - why would we have the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag if it wasn't OK?

Comment: Turns out questions about questions about why a question is downvoted are also legitimate.

Comment: @Patrice You're a lurker? Could've fooled me...

Comment: If not a possible duplicate, then entirely relevant: [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta)

Comment: This might be relevant: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.yiuo0ce09

Comment: re: shaming voters into being more thoughtful... the process which people will follow to "educate" people is generally a thousand times more shameful than the act itself. There is a good reason voting is anonymous in most facets of civilization.

Comment: Just a remark: it depends on communities. On [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/), you get a message recommending to leave a comment when you downvote. On SO, I have often read advice for not commenting a downvote. I personnaly try to improve a post when there's a comment; but I just delete a post that is downvoted without comments without even wondering whether it could be improved.

Comment: @meagar It's questions all the way down.

Comment: @DigitalFire just read that article, but I feel that it tried to make the leap from "here are a few stats showing that first-time posters tend not to come back" (at least under the same account... which is true for a lot of sites, not just Q&A) to "omg knowledgeable people are leaving SO" without providing anything beyond anecdotal support for the latter, and blaming this on trolling (which in this case is using the downvote/close mechanisms provided by the site -- gasp -- not really harassment) with pretty tenuous connections there too

Comment: *downvoted a question about a question about a downvoted question*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's fine to ask about it, but do bear in mind that in asking about it...you will incite a lot of attention to yourself and your downvoted question.

The problem is with that "extra attention", even though it's what's explicitly requested.  Supposing that one is voicing disagreement with their question being downvoted, and they are fully convinced that this is entirely unjustified, they could get a lot of backlash; they might receive anything from *more* downvotes on it due to it being brought to Meta's attention to snide comments about its quality.

The more constructive of these discussions tend to have constructive criticism that the OP can use to fix their question and help them out in the future, which is the more ideal scenario.  In this instance, the OP has to realize and accept that their question wasn't the best, and coming here with that kind of mindset is, in my mind, a *good* thing; a person that comes to Meta to improve their question, out of a thousand other people that ask terrible questions, is well worth helping.  The main thing is that humility piece needs to be present.

Of course we do have the run-of-the-mill [why should we downvote questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/1079354) answer for those who ask *why*, but for those that actually ask, "How can I make this better?", those are the sorts of questions which are good to have around on Meta.

Just gotta keep your eyes open for the right kind.

Comment: "The main thing is that humility piece needs to be present." That sounds very strange to me. You mean, askers should show extreme humility in order to appear in the right mindset to be considered for help instead of further downvotes? Are we that superficial or capricious? Do askers need to maybe flatter the meta inhabitants first? I think that many bits in this answer are right, but the very strong emphasis on realizing and accepting that their question wasn't the best may be a bit too much. It makes the community here seeming overly picky.

Comment: @Trilarion: After reading so many questions that put the blame of a question being closed on the community at large, an attitude that *isn't* that is refreshing.  Perhaps "humility" is too strong of a word?

Comment: Makoto, look at a choice of synonyms for [humility](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/humility). I agree with @Trilarion that this should not be the mindset we are asking for. Alas, as I am not a native speaker, I can't come up with a single phrase for "allowing to concede the possibility that the question is indeed asked wrong".

Comment: @Trilarion: Do you really have a problem with expecting humility from someone who is looking for help with a disagreement about the applicability of downvotes, or trying to figure out how they went wrong? Humility is only appropriate, in either case. I don't know why you jumped from that to "extreme" humility and the idea of humiliating or flagellating oneself. (That is counterproductive and pointless.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy As I said. It sounds strange to me. I think the emphasis on it is too strong. Maybe you could give examples of what you mean by humility and the right set of mind? I might just not understand you and Makoto well enough? The things I would focus on instead are included in my answer below.

Comment: *"..a person that comes to Meta to improve their question, out of a thousand other people that ask terrible questions, is well worth helping"* This. If that's genuinely what they're doing.

Comment: @nbrooks:  "Incite" was a good choice in this case as opposed to invite, since the Meta Effect can be uninvited and unwarranted at times.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I assumed it was a typo since the keys are neighboring on the keyboard. I still think you're looking for 'invite' though. You can 'incite' retaliation, or 'incite' a down-vote spree, but you can't 'incite' attention. By unintentionally inviting attention, you might incite down-voting though. Just a language note though, I'll let you decide how best to word your response.

Comment: @nbrooks:  You can incite the Meta Effect.  That's where I was going with it.  But thank you.

Comment: @Trilarion: A humble person is aware of their own limitations, including the limitations they don't specifically know of, and does not start out by assuming others are at fault. A humble person does not consider themselves the #1 authority on a subject by default, even if they know themselves to be *an* authority, but assumes others may know better, if only in specific areas.

Comment: Replace humility with open mindness?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, I agree with that. To put these general guidelines a bit more into practice, would for example "I may be wrong but I think for reasons X and Y a mistake could have been made at point Z. What do you think about it?" be in the spirit of humbleness? If so, we just need to kind of present a template and then we can start discussing the contents. I now think that all I want is to discuss less about the form of how such an enquiry should be presented as long as minimal standards are satisfied but more about if the real content-related issues should be answered or not be answered.

Comment: @Trilarion: More or less, yes. It's important to start out right, but continuing humility is also necessary, so there's perhaps a bit of a hidden risk in expecting an initial template to do all the work.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sure, but there is also a hidden risk of acting overly picky and wasting time of everyone letting people search for the most humble approach which may be impossible since one cannot please everyone all the time. I think that in the end the easiest solution is probably to just concentrate on the facts. Get these right and get the form good enough and everything will be fine. We could start every contribution of everyone here with "I may be wrong but..." but we don't because it would become an empty phrase soon even though it would be totally true.

Answer (score 8):

If you are asking about votes on META: indeed you can, but it is not a good idea - large portion of votes on META is about "I agree/disagree that this is useful proposal" and rarely about technical quality of the post itself.

Make sure to read existing explanation like [Why are votes on Meta so passionate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325635/why-are-votes-on-meta-so-passionate). Unless you have significant new insight I would not ask question about voting on META itself anymore (as there is many existing posts on it).

If you have alternative suggestion on particular existing downvoted/closed META questions - it is better to just ask again with clear explanation why same question is brought up (i.e. new feature on SO makes it different, new policy,...). Make sure to carefully read comment threads on existing posts so first - unlike SO there is generally enough explanations for votes on META.

---

If you are asking about votes on SO: Yes, it is perfectly ok to ask here on META about why question received negatively on SO.

Keep in mind that linking from META has similar effect to bounties - it gives a lot of attention to question, mostly without initiative to provide answer. See [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Make sure you are open to negative feedback - plenty of such META questions endup with "all META are complete #$#$# and don't get how my SO question is awesome" comments from OP. Asking why question was received negatively and expecting consolation is not what META is for.

Also before posting read some of existing posts on META around [specific-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) - this will give you a list of known reasons why posts are downvoted as well as set your expectation on type of discussions that are happening about questions. Re-reading SO tour and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is another good step you should take and first review your own questions yourself with information about potential reasons.

Comment: "you are complete #$#$# and don't get my awesome questions" Did you mean: ***awesome answers***

Comment: @dorukayhan thanks. I've tried to rephrase that ... I did mean "awesome SO questions"...

Comment: Meta isn't an acronym though :)

Comment: @cat: Are you sure it's not an acronym for `Meta Exists To Argue` ?

Comment: @MSalters Uhh, I think Meta is more about hating fun than arguing, but if you say so...

Answer (score 2):

A downvoted and/or closed question cannot get any worse.

For insights into the meta effect (things that can happen when contributing to meta) see the other excellent answers here by Alexei Levenkov and Makoto.

My best advice for when discussing downvoted and/or closed questions: Stick to the facts! No opinions but just arguments and facts! No questioning of the rules of StackOverflow. (Do that separately if you need to.)

Make a case, state what confuses you or what you are unable to do and ask for help!

You might still see unexpected results from the meta effect but chances are high you will learn something (from an answer or maybe from a comment). And anyway: A downvoted and/or closed question cannot get any worse.