# Why does Meta Stack Overflow have more views and votes compared to the other sites

Tags: discussion, meta, views

The questions and answers in Stack Overflow Meta have more views and votes as compared to any other Stack Exchange site.

Why and how is this so?

Comment: Any other site or any other meta site?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other meta sites.

Comment: Arbitrary example: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's 'other stack overflow sites'. 1 sec. Is it Stack Exchange site? yup. Any other stack exchange site

Comment: @duplode why you've send me to chemistry?

Comment: SO has 6.5 million user accounts.  The next biggest site (mathematics) has *twenty times* fewer accounts.  So MSO ought to have about 20 times more questions.  It doesn't, it only has 4 times more questions than meta.math.  Well, perhaps mathematicians are better at creating only one account and remembering its name.

Comment: [related meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325635/why-are-votes-on-meta-so-passionate) and also [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/3627607)

Comment: @Prabs It was just an arbirtrary example of another meta site.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is simple; there are fewer questions (and answers) here than on the main site. Therefore, they are visible for a longer period of time and attract more visitors (even though many people rarely visit meta). I'm not sure if people are quicker to vote than on the main site or not – I can try to figure this out with a SEDE query.

Furthermore, there's a 'Featured on Meta / Hot Meta posts' box on the main site, which attracts more visitors.

This phenomenon happens for all sites in the Stack Exchange network (each site has its own Meta – e.g. [Android Enthousiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) has [Meta Android Enthousiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/)). Because Stack Overflow is by far the largest community, its Meta site is also the most popular.

Comment: You may add that the votes doesn't impact reputation and are used to show agreement/disagreement (on feature request at first, but also on every post finally)

Comment: @Tensibai yes, I was thinking that as well, but I don't want to make such claims without data to back it up.

Comment: Indeed it's more an observation on every downvoted post when author ask for why, the answer is usually because it shows "agreement/disgreement" I'd be curious to see how often this happen on negatively voted Q on meta.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to vote more often on Meta because it's easier to agree/disagree than to judge an answer's usefulness.

Comment: Unsure it is data, but the [meta faq post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/3627607) has an answer about it.