# How to attach document or image in this forum?

Tags: discussion, design

I am trying to attach some log file or image in this forum.But unable to do,it shows you need 10-reputation to post an image or link.Could any one suggest me how to add some log files and images in the post.

Regards,
Poornima

Comment: What part of "you need 10 reputation" is unclear? Make contributions to the site to increase your reputation points.

Comment: what kind of contributions needed to increase my reputation points

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: if you need to increase your reputation then check the stackoverflow reputation documentation please. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: First of all **This is not a forum**

Comment: Also note that actually needing to attach an image to explain your problem is quite uncommon (explanations in words and code are generally more useful), and needing to attach a log file is even rarer (you can just paste it into the question, except perhaps if it is very long -- in that case, though, you should edit it to only include the parts relevant to your issue anyway).

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: ok.Thank you very much.will try to follow your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase your reputation you need to:

- ask good questions (you got 5 reputation if someone upvote your
  question)
- answer to questions (you got 15 reputation if your answer
  solved the question and 10 reputation if someone upvote your answer)
- if you accept an answer (for example this) you got an another 2 reputation

Comment: _if you accept an answer (for example this_ no rep on meta activities

Comment: you forgot about edit suggestions. [Approved edit gives +2 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suggested-edits/info) meaning five good edits will suffice to allow posting images