# What to do when one faces with so many bad advices outnumbering the only good advice?

Tags: discussion

I recently bumped into a thread in which many up-voted comments and answers are actually bad advice or anti patterns. When I tried to express my criticism, I was outnumbered by all the noise and even one person (the one whose answer is marked as best) tried to argue despite his/her apparent lack of knowledge on the subject. I literally feel bad for the future readers of the topic, since I know what is written there will cause headaches in the future if they obey the suggestions blindly.

Comment: If have a better answer, write one. If you're downvoted by many people do consider the possibility that it's you and not them who's wrong.

Comment: *outnumbering the only good advice*  If by this you mean there's an existing answer you agree with then vote it up and consider leaving a comment explaining why you think that answer is the best/correct one. It may help someone scanning the answers to see something like, "This answer avoids security issue [blah]."

Comment: It wasn't me, was it?  I often get into SO bar fights over thread termination and/or freeing all memory before process termination:(

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect us to say or do. You have not linked in the specific question, so we cannot take a look at it and decide ourselves which answers are the right one. Sometimesyou just haveto let it go.

Comment: We don't have threads here. [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Write a better answer.**

That way, the community can benefit from it.

Honestly, if you are 100% sure that you know the subject better/know about a concern that the others don't, the community of that particular topic *will* appreciate your insight.

Comment: This is pretty much it; once you've made your position clear, well, [your duty is done](https://xkcd.com/386/).