# Improper thread dates

Tags: discussion

I've just approved an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/48270314#48270314), it shows as "edited 6 min ago Joshua". But I wonder, why the original answer had been made "2 days ago"? If you go through the all thread, you see that the Question and all of its Answers and all of theirs Comments have 1-2 days ago dates. This is obviously the old thread. Is it a bug or what happens?

[image]

Comment: what? What is confusing here? Kevin B answered 2 days ago, and 6 minutes ago Joshua updated that answer...

Comment: @Patrice And gained 1481 upvotes?

Comment: Yeah, improper date treads are best avoided. wait.

Comment: @Patrice going by the circles it seems it's implied that the dates are wrong because of the question and answer scores

Comment: gained 1481 upvotes? Yes. this has been on the HNQ. And presumably linked from somewhere external judging by the view count. (Edit both HN and Reddit) https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16161030 https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7r0i00/can_a_1_a_2_a3_ever_evaluate_to_true/

Comment: actually, the only sad thing is they won't be gaining all them reps

Comment: @dhit yes, as Martin said, HNQ to the right. It skews vote. Not a new problem or issue.

Comment: The question with the Id immediately after that one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270128/error-with-square-checkout-api-the-order-has-expired

Comment: hax  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ..

Comment: We don't have threads here. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: here's the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48270314/timeline

Comment: 2014 up votes now.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an old thread. [I have an answer on it too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287889/1663383). It showed up in Hot Network Questions and being someone who knows a thing or two about Javascript (although I don't follow the tag), I ended up writing an answer.

At the time I wrote the answer, Kevin's post had a much more modest 150 up votes or so (I even upvoted it).  Here's my reputation tab for the last two-three days:

[image: Reputation panel]

Comment: It was probably linked in many places since everyone reading this will be going "wtf" and will then share it on their work chat, favourite IRC channel, subreddit, etc. accompanied with a comment on how silly JavaScript is (that's what I did, anyway ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Entirely probable. Only place **I** shared it was to a friend with the comment "I rep-capped on SO again."

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/7qv7pu/javascript_can_a_1_a_2_a3_ever_evaluate_to_true/