# Asking questions as a beginner/newbie

Tags: discussion

Just starting out with modelling, there is A LOT of information to take in...

Every minute of my process, I discover new things and a lot of which I do not entirely understand.

So I found this forum, but because I'm so new to this, I find it extremely hard to ask questions that people will give clear and understandable asnwers to without it being downvoted immediately because of my lack of knowledge.

The forum is strictly stating that "you should do your research before asking". And I do that, every time actually, but I rarely find clear answers to my, generally speaking, basic questions.

I guess my quesion is: Can I ask easy questions on here, even if there maybe is an answer to them somewhere out there?

Please give kind advice thanks!

Comment: Just note: This is not a forum. Don't expect forum-like interactions.

Comment: _even if there maybe is an answer to them somewhere out there?_ that would likely be closed as a duplicate if it is already present in SO. finding it is part of expected research

Comment: You could have read the [tour] when signing up. There is also a Help Center which includes topics such as "How do I ask a good question?"

Comment: On MSE: [How can a noob ask questions about "how to start with this cool stuff"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181993)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: a more stark reality is it is a place to ask ["Give me ur codez pls"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48357619/2564301) and get an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can I ask easy questions on here, even if there maybe is an answer to them somewhere out there?

You are expected to do your own research before asking questions on Stack Overflow. We're not a traditional forum that's set up to help individuals directly with one-on-one answers to every question. Stack Overflow is designed to be a repository of information so that you find answers to your questions as you search *because those answers already exist*. If you're asking questions that have already been answered on Stack Overflow, you can expect downvotes and for your questions to be closed.

That said, you *can* ask "easy" questions *after* you've done your research and not found an answer. Just be prepared to show what research you've done. Don't just ask for links pointing you in the right direction. Link to resources you've already found and explain in detail what it is you don't understand. Ask clarifying questions based on what you already know.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you absolutely can.

However, I took a look at a profile and only found one question you asked ([Mdriven attribute.type explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269645/mdriven-attribute-type-explenations)). Just to explain why this question got downvotes and is likely to be closed: It is just way too broad. Understandably, you learn a lot of new stuff when entering a completely new area so sometimes you don't even now what to ask for. When you ask

> Where can I find more detailed explanations for different attribute.type?

It is not a good question for Stack Overflow, because we do not recommend outside resources. Also, your next question is introduced with a "For example:", which makes it clear to me that you actually have many more questions to follow.

If you don't know the basics and are in general "lost" in the topic, Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for you. I would recommend to first get familiar with the subject, e.g. with books, courses, or online material. If you then have **concrete** questions you are more than welcome to ask them.