# Formatting Code Snippets in Stack Overflow Posts

Tags: discussion

I have searched the forums and have not found a specific answer for this question.  I recently posted my first answer on here and included a code snippet.  It was a single line so the formatting of the content was not that important.

I do see several responses and even questions where the code snippets reflect the "style" formatting of the application.  I used the brackets and saw this: `,CAST (Table1.DateTime1-Table2.Time_Enroute as time) as [Response Travel Time]`

I used the "<>" icon and tried all of the options and settled on the HTML option.  This resulted in:

```html
,CAST (Table1.DateTime1-Table2.Time_Enroute as time) as [Response Travel Time]
```

So the question is, how do I post a snippet formatted like I've seen in some posts where the code would be formatted like it is in the application?:
[Code Snippet from SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThPet.png)

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: What forums? [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [code-sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvKXA.png) option by either:

- click the {} button in the toolbar;
- select your code and press ctrl+K;
- add 4 spaces in front of your line of code

This will be your result:

```
,CAST (Table1.DateTime1-Table2.Time_Enroute as time) as [Response Travel Time]
```

To have the proper *prettifier* add the best fitting [syntax-highlighting hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) by adding `<!-- language: lang-default -->`  on a line by itself.

The total markup will look like this

> ```
> <!-- language: lang-default -->
>
>    ,CAST (Table1.DateTime1-Table2.Time_Enroute as time) as [Response Travel Time]
> ```

Comment: I don't think it can be emphasized enough: Do NOT use Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) for anything other than code that demonstrates something important about the HTML/CSS/JS question when the "Run code snippet" button is clicked.