# Beginner's Confusion on Minimum Reproducible Example and Debugging

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions, debugging-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

Beginner here to coding and the forums. I recently posted a question here: ([Why are my python functions failing to return correct output (algebra error)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756742/why-are-my-python-functions-failing-to-return-correct-output-algebra-error)) that was rejected. I just wanted to learn why as there were some comments about MRE and Debugging. For some background, I've had a look at all the MRE and Debugging Articles linked in those comments, but they were quite technical so I apologise if I couldn't understand much from there.

For MRE, I looked at my code and edited out the unnecessary parts and kept it down to the essentials of what was needed as there was very specific algebra there. In the future, should I have made entirely new code? I'm not really sure what I did wrong here but would love to know.

For Debugging, I assume that just means looking through the code error and seeing what is causing the errors, but I have done that and the code ran fine, just that the code's roots are different from the mathematically correct roots by Wolfram Alpha.

So I'm just a little confused, thanks in advance!

Comment: 'For Debugging, I assume that just means looking through the code error and seeing what is causing the errors' 'just'?    Debugging is an essential skill, without which you cannot program computers.  Skilled and experienced developers are not paid well for writing code - they are valued because they can get the system working to spec, (or, at least, close enough that customers will pay up:)

Comment: Hi @MartinJames, thanks for responding. I'm still a little bit confused, I get that debugging is an essential skill, but I just don't know what I did wrong in my post to not 'debug' it? As I said, I looked through the code to see if there's any coding errors, but the output just wasn't the same as wolfram alpha's, so I figure it must have just been an algebra error (ie. the 'bug). But I still couldn't pinpoint why it existed as I scrutinised the whole code.

Comment: @GildedCrowEscapee If your question is closed because it "needs debugging details", then it means that you didn't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), error message, or posted images of code or errors

Comment: Apparently, your issue was caused by a typo on the input (which the question will be closed again for this reason, if it got reopened...)

Comment: Very relevant: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You can also take the [advice from this external site](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: The code is just hard to read due to lack of spaces, I don't see any other problem with the question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum.  Do you see the word "forum" anywhere in the UI? Its a question and answer repository.  Only questions that are of value should remain in this repository.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: I was using the term 'forums' loosely as just an online discussion or question and answer resource.

Comment: @oguzismail I'm a bit confused then, so was that the only problem?