# Why do I get downvotes on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvote-reason

I don't care whether I am upvoted or downvoted as long as it is justified. But now I'm annoyed because a question was downvoted.

Perhaps because a question is "too stupid" for someone or it is not understood. I dont know. But isn't this a forum to ask unanswered questions?

An example is this question:
[c# Reading out Microsoft Installer Patch (MSP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517524/c-sharp-reading-out-microsoft-installer-patch-msp)

Why do I get a negative rating here? Maybe someone can explain this to me in detail?

Comment: I think you might want to know about [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: From what I can tell, your Question isn't very well described. It would be better if you could tell what you're trying to do with more details. Also, don't use images when you can use text. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  page is important to read and know about before you ask Questions. It specifically says "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc". It looks to me that it's impossible to see "MsiPatchMetadata" without looking at the image.

Comment: As an aside, that answer is not what I would consider high-quality as it is more of a code-dump answer, one without textual information that describes the cause of the problem in detail, the proposed solution, and how the proposed code solves the problem. In my own personal view, it is more deserving of a down-vote than the question. And yeah, the meta effect....

Comment: I didn't downvote - but think before posting any question 'Did I put as much effort into solving this before I posted?' and 'Is this going to be useful for other people?'. If you can answer yes to both of them, you have a much better chance of not being downvoted.

Comment: To Scrate:

a good question should have...
# a title that summarizes the specific problem <= Check
# a good spelling, grammar and punctuation <= good enought for 2 sentenses, 1 picture and a link to a post who describes my problem 100%.

I think I did everything right. But it's like clothes. For one or the other, the red tie is better. ;-)

Yes and no as far as the meta-effect is concerned

Comment: to user438383:

I always think very carefully whether I am asking a question for which I cannot find a solution. Do I have to state how much effort I have invested in solving the problem? How am I supposed to weigh up whether another person finds this useful?

Comment: Where does it say "1 picture and a link to a post who describes my problem" is a part of a good Question? Questions need to be self-contained. Linking to some other post makes it not self-contained. Note that if you're here to explain how your Question is just fine as is, then I think you came to the wrong place.

Comment: @Scratte: In the example given, there is a heading, a question, a link to the topic and an embedded image to illustrate the problem.

I do not understand your question...

Comment: We're telling you that your Question is not fine. And giving you the reasons why it's not fine. Stating that you think it's fine doesn't make it so. As I already mentioned: 1. Explain in more details what you're trying to do. 2. Post text, so people with screen readers can still understand your post. How is a blind person able to understand your Question? About the post being self-contained. What happens if that other Questions is deleted? Does your post still make sense?

Comment: Does your posting make sense? They explain to me that I did wrong what hundreds did before me. You may not like it. I accept that, but I don't have to be of the same opinion.

in fact, a formal error seems to be a reason for many to punish rather than answer.

Reason enough for me to leave Stackoverflow.

Comment: You may be overreacting a bit, but it's your choice in what you eventually do

Comment: Re *"isn't this a forum"*: [Stack Overflow is ***NOT*** a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Why did you think so?

Comment: Rage quitting is an immature reaction. Have a little empathy for the readers of your posts and read your posts at least once, fixing at least the most obvious errors (instead of a write-only post) - there is an "Edit" link on each. There are on the order of five spelling mistakes in every sentence of yours. Your English sucks (at least as demonstrated in the posts here), but the good news is there are three things you can change that will have great effect and require no or very little skill: 1) Install or enable a spell checker in your browser 2) Capitalise "i" 3) Capitalise sentences. -

Comment: cont' - 4) [Remove salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) and other meta information (this can be put in comments if you really feel compelled to say it). Future readers and voters will thank you (though not in advance).

Comment: You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62200803/edit). (Words the spell checker does not know the answer to: [cmdlet](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Cmdlet) and [Visual Studio](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=VisualStudio).)

Comment: You don't leave Stack Overflow by having your account deleted. Your posts are still there and It'll still be there in all of the top search results of programming related searches. I really don't know what people hope to achieve. I delete my account! Ha ha, take that! ... me and nobody else?

Answer (score 9):

It's impossible to say why people are downvoting a post since everyone can vote freely. However, we can make educated guesses why people find this question unhelpful.

Your question isn't very well described. What exactly do you want to read from the file? How do you want to process this file? The question is not terrible, but if you could explain it a little bit more clearly what outcome you expect, it would help with answering it.

You have posted an answer that doesn't explain anything. It doesn't teach us anything as there's no explanation. I still don't know how to 'read out Microsoft Installer Patch'.

Stack Overflow is meant to be an educational tool. The question is meant to pose a clear simple problem and the answer is meant to explain and teach how to achieve the solution. The code isn't necessary in either case, but it certainly helps to understand the problem and the solution.

Comment: So your first sentence applies pretty broadly if we were talking about a question that was otherwise well-written. It's a *little* hard to accept that for this *specific* question, that a lot of people dropped their keys on this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you come here *asking* for code, you're gonna have a bad time.

If you come here looking for help with *your* code, you'll *probably* fare a lot better.

A glance at your question suggests that you're looking for code as opposed to asking why your own code to accomplish what you're looking to do isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Makoto! Using the example in the link, you can see the code. If I don't even know where to start ...

How much useless code should I post before someone can/wants to give a tip?

Just the lack of a code example is enough to get a negative rating?
Conversely, does someone in school get a bad grade if they ask?

Comment: @Chris *"Conversely, does someone in school get a bad grade if they ask?"* ... If the concept of the school tells you to put some effort in and research the topic first, then yes, you can expect bad grades for not doing so.

Comment: @Chris - We can only read what you have written.  If we are interpreting your words incorrectly, edit your words, so they are interpreted properly.  Asking a question without a single line of code is a problem.

Comment: "If I don't even know where to start" Unfortunately for you, Stack Overflow cannot help you in such case. It is meant to be place for asking very specific questions about specific problems. If you don't know where to start that means you haven't defined your problem (besides, I don't know how to do X) and this is why we cannot help you. We don't know what you don't know and what are particular obstacles you face. You will have to start breaking down what you want to do in steps and then each well defined step you get stuck is potential question.

Comment: ... but before you ask a question, you should search to see whether that problem already has a solution. This is the whole point of SO, to have answers to common problems that can be found when you get stuck on a problem.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I don't entirely agree with that. I think How-To Questions are Stack's biggest assets. Debugging Questions.. not so much. Adding code to How-To Questions makes them less useful.

Comment: @Scratte Well defined "how to" questions that have narrow scope. When "how to" question requires writing a book, then it is too broad.

Comment: @Chris: The point is for you to showcase what you've got and where you're stuck. If you have nothing to show as progress for what you've built, then you're not in a point where you're asking a question - you're asking us to build this parser for you. If you have *something* and you can showcase what you tried and what you got back when it failed, *then* you're in a better spot to ask a question. At that point, you'll *know* what it is you're looking for.