# Why are Stack Exchange Staff listed as Moderators?

Tags: support, moderators, stack-exchange-team

If you view all users in Stack Overflow, you can sort by moderators and can see the lot of them.

However, none of those listed are Stack Exchange staff.

But, very clearly, we can see that when *staff* post on the forum they have the `moderator` tag.

It is assumed that since staff are higher on the figurative and literal totem poles that they would have access to all privileges a mere moderator would have.

Thus, this begs the question. Are there even any staff that aren't listed as moderators?

If so, I think the moderator tag should be removed from staff as it is redundant.

Comment: Not all staff members are moderators. If you filter to "Announcement" posts, you'll see one.

Comment: Some staff need moderator privileges as part of their job regardless of whether they've reached any reputation threshold. Not all staff need these privileges; that part of your assumption is incorrect/incomplete. So staff that get them have the 'moderator' tag applied next to their name on posts and in the profile.

Comment: Shouldn't you find out more about how the system works before getting involved in such recommendations?

Comment: eh, it's not unreasonable to not know what you don't know, and to act according to what you do (or think you do) know

Comment: Related: [What privileges and tools do staff members without a diamond have access to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344146/241919)

Comment: @charlietfl making feature requests would be a little hasty indeed, but asking questions is exactly what you should never be stopped from doing on meta.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My mod badge tells anyone looking that I have access to the same tools that a moderator does - which means I can issue mod messages with and without suspensions, review flags, unilaterally close and delete posts... and also that I have all privileges on the site unlocked (e.g. closing, deleting, editing, etc) without having the reputation required for those actions.

As mentioned in comments, not all staff have these abilities. Most staff, in fact, have none of them. Without a mod indicator on a staff account, staff have no access to any of the moderation tools, only a few things such as the ability to write posts on meta without 5 reputation and some abilities to retag posts on meta or use status-tags here, too.

But I hope you understand the value of having an indicator that differentiates between the two groups - I think that it's obvious but, if it's not - it makes it immediately clear to the people who understand this difference whether someone has certain abilities or access or not.

While we don't have an exhaustive list of the differences of access between staff with moderation abilities and those without, the main goal of having two changes is to limit access and information to only those who should have it rather than giving it to everyone within the company by default. The principle of least privilege in practice.

Comment: And that's a good thing.  That you can moderate a webserver does not imply you can moderate humans. Different skillsets and different toolchains.

Comment: Yeah, humans are much more finicky and have a lot more compatibility problems than your average web server. Fortunately, Stack Overflow's mission is not really to moderate humans, but rather to moderate content. Unfortunately, that's even harder.

Comment: Not super exhaustive, but Yaakov did [elaborate on what the `IsEmployee` flag does on my question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344146/622284).