# Wouldn't it make sense to have quick links directly below the thread starter's question, if there are accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-experience, homepage, navigation

is there a way to get a direct link to an accepted answer? I've seen this in a few other forums, and it seems logical to me.

The total discussion is of course very relevant also, just different modes of searching for an answer.

Comment: *"I've seen this in a few other forums"* [so] isn't a forum, so it doesn't work like one.

Comment: The accepted answer also isn't always the most upvoted. The answer with the most upvotes is often a far better indicator of what answer should be used (though not always), and hence why it's the default sort order.

Comment: You mean aside from the URL for the answer itself, or the "share" URL available underneath it? Not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: I think this is meant to refer to those forums that preview the accepted answer just under the question, but that doesn't really make sense. All answers are answers here, there's no need to lift it up to make acceptance distinct

Comment: I guess you want something like "pinning the accepted answer at the top". This was changed last year and was previously discussed there => [Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/5893316).

Comment: Isn't it significantly easier to just scroll down (as opposed to having to first locate some button or link amongs myriad others, and then having to click it, so it scrolls the page)? I mean with a mouse it's just a flick of a finger on a scroll wheel, and on a touch screen it's just as simple...

Comment: I have a slight suspicion I've seen a feature request exactly like it recently, might be a dupe - does anyone remember the exact post by any chance? If I find it, will VTC

Comment: Re *"...the thread"*: We don't have threads here. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Why did you think it was a forum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow is **not** a forum, it's a Q&A site, which really isn't the same thing. Also, Stack Overflow doesn't have threads, it has questions and answers.

The comments already pointed this out, but [accepting an answer no longer pins it to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top); this was recently changed at the request of the community. Most people felt that the fact that an answer is accepted does not necessarily mean that it's the "best" answer (just that it was the OP's favorite answer at the time that they accepted it).

Overall, I'm really not sure what the point of this is. It typically makes sense to look at the top-voted answer first (because that is what most other readers have found the most useful), which is what the site already does.

If you're talking about getting a link that you can share with others, this feature already exists; there's a "share" button under each post, so you can share a direct link to whatever question (or answer, or even comment) you prefer. This isn't just limited to the accepted answer or the question.

Comment: I think it actually does [have threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading) :) I know, I know, I will see myself out.

Comment: Hello! My bad using the term "forum", when I was actually having a simlar site in mind, as I wrote the question, but I didn't want to drop names ;). I should have used the term "Q&A site" if that makes more sense to us. 

My only intent was to speed up navigation, jumping to "the accepted answer" straight away. But if the top voted bubbles up to the top, that's perhaps pretty relevant, I would agree. I wasn't aware.  

If we call this a "Q&A" site, what *actually* answers the original poster's question, could be rewarded with a direct link, next to the original question.